# System.NullReferenceException when i try to add a value to my List

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I got a class who looks like this.

```
public class PostUndKey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<int> Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> von_datum { get; set; }
    public List<string> bis_datum { get; set; }
}
```

In my Code i use something like this.

```
PostUndKey x = new PostUndKey();
var z = 42;
x.Id.Add(z);
```

And i always get the Null Reference Exception.
Can someone explain this to me pls i dont get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `List<int>` and assign it to `Id` property. `List<T>` is a reference type and [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) for reference type is `null`. For example:

```cs
PostUndKey x = new PostUndKey();
x.Id = new List<int>();
var z = 42;
x.Id.Add(z);
```

Or initialize `Id` for `PostUndKey` instance creation:

```cs
public class PostUndKey
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<int> Id { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<string> von_datum { get; set; }
    public List<string> bis_datum { get; set; }
}
```

Read more:

- [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)
- [Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)